# Umbraco event for document sort?

Tags: sorting, event-handling, umbraco

Are there events which fire when you use the **sort** functionality of the content document tree?

I had assumed that there may be events similar to:

*umbraco.cms.businesslogic.web.**Document.BeforeMove***

Is there an object other than *Document* that I am overlooking for an event hook for content sorting?

The class I'm using to handle custom events uses *umbraco.businesslogic.**ApplicationStartupHandler*** as its base class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/using-applicationbase-to-register-events/overview-of-all-events) is a cheatsheet of all the API events, sorted by type of object they apply to. There is no event for a sort, unfortunately.

However (and I'm thinking out loud here) after the sort you will either have an UpdateDocumentCache event at some point, or a RefreshContent event. Would it not be possible to hook into those instead?

Comment: The class to use is _umbraco.content_. The events _AfterUpdateDocumentCache_ or _BeforeUpdateDocumentCache_ can be used. They are called for each Document in the sort list in the new sort order.

Comment: Thanks Andrei. I'm using this to synchronize the content trees of different language in a multilingual application.

Comment: That's interesting, and an approach I never considered - usually when building multilingual sites, I treat them as completely separate applications. So, while they may be hosted in the same Umbraco instance and share specific content, their actual structure does not need to stay in absolute sync. Again, thinking out loud, if you have some content that needs to stay in sync across all hostnames, would it not be better to take it outside the actual site content trees, and just reference it/load it as needed?